# TypeError: Cannot read property 'first1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, node-modules

there are two classes ( I created new instance from first class in main class )

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'first1' of undefined**

```
export default class main {
  first1: first
  constructor() {
    this.first1 = new first()
  } 
  async list(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const { result } = await this.first1.list({ limit: req.query.limit, page: 
                         req.query.page, filters: req.query.filters })
      res.status(200).json(result)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      CatchError(error, next)
    }
  }
}
```

```
export default class first{

  async list({ limit, page, filters }) {
    let result: {data:"ssssssss"}
    return { result }
  }

}
```

Comment: What's point of assigning value first to first1 property to object of main class when you are assigning value to the same property in constructor

Comment: Please explain how you initialize your `main` instance?

Comment: Please show us how you create a `new main` instance and how you call `.list()` on it.

Comment: `export default class xyzRouter {
  router: Router
  private main1 = new main()

  constructor() {
    this.router = Router()
    this.routes()
  }
  private routes() {
    this.router.get("/", this.main1.list)
  }
}`

Comment: That's what I guessed: `this.main1.list` is not a method call, your passing an unbound function around. See the duplicate for how to fix this. Or maybe don't use `class` instances for everything, this wouldn't have happened with a simple `function`